# How to change an element's size at runtime on an CRM 2016 form

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to change the height of a DIV element (which is a multiple line text field) in my CRM 2016 form when loading or saving the form so that the element expands and displays all its content.

I know that there is a form option to expand fields but it can only be used for one field in a tab and there is already another field that uses that setting.

I also know that an option is to place the field in another tab and use the expand setting, but I am wondering if there is any way (short of accessing the DOM as Microsoft does not support it in CRM 2016) to get hold of the field/element in the page on the fly and change its height. Can this be done using Xrm.Page libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot do this in a supported way. Requires DOM manipulation in Form load JS.

Right now auto-expanding is having a product limitation to have only 1 control in a tab.

[image]